# Importing Selenium Webdriver from Maven to Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea, webdriver

So I wanted to move from Python + Selenium to Java + Selenium. I decided to follow up Selenium documentation and use Maven. I use Intellij IDEA as my IDE. I created project directory, where I placed pom.xml taken from [this link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) with version of **selenium-java** artifact changed to **2.35.0**. Then I did

```
mvn clean install
```

After that I imported Maven project to IDEA by using "Import project from Maven". All external libraries are added, but when I try to import Selenium modules it seems that IDE does not recognize them (cannot resolve symbol). Can anyone give me a hand with that? Probably there is something missing n project settings, or any other configuration error?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. You must create a java module in the maven project directory (it's already your project directory), not in a separate-directory, without creating a project directory inside the Maven, and then all the dependencies will be catch up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Maven did import the dependencies 
It is not clear from your screenshot if you've created a new class
(Missing package,Class name, methods...)

Try in your IntelliJ:

1. Right click on your project tree
2. New->Java class
3. Name it SeleniumTest (or any other name)
4. Create a new method:
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   }
5. Add the missing imports

Let me know if it helps or if you need more assistance

Answer (score 0):

Here's what helped me. After importing the project:

1. Create a `src` folder manually.
2. Open the File — Project Structure — Modules
3. Select your project.

   [image]
4. Mark the `src` folder as source location
   [image]